# JavaSE 7 URL Timing out that works in JavaSE 6?

Tags: java, networking, timeout, java-7

The following code works fine in JavaSE 6 but is throwing a ConnectException (timeout) when executed in JavaSE 7.  Is this a JDK7 bug or bad code?  I really don't understand...

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34206572/version.txt");
        url.openConnection().connect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Comment: I just tried this code it worked fine in both 1.7.0 and 1.6.0_25. What exact version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code in 1.7.0_02-b13, it works fine. I visit the link above, it is not available (page 404 is returned).

Maybe, you mean that the following code crashes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
    URL url = new URL("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34206572/version.txt");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 

    InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();             
}
```

with following exception (I formatted it out):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
                  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34206572/version.txt
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(
                                    HttpURLConnection.java:1610)
```